# What's the name of this small plant with six-lobed umbrella-like leaves?

Tags: identification

[image: ground cover]

I think it's native of Virginia.

Answer (score 3):

It's a Mayapple (*Podophyllum peltatum*). They are native to most of the Eastern US, mainly in woodlands. They expand largely by rhizomes underground. In New York this past week they were just coming into bloom. If you peak under the leaves there might still be a small white flower there, or it might have started to produce a fruit if there are other mayapples in the area for it to pollinate with.

It's not dangerous to touch, but DO NOT let anything you care about eat it. The entire plant is highly poisonous with the exception of fully ripened fruit.